# WifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks always returns empty list

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I am trying to connect to an open wifi network. When I open my app it should turn on wifi and connect to the network defined as below. The problem is that `WifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks` always returns me an empty list. I have tried using locks too without success.

```
WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;        
conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
conf.priority = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);   
wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);


List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
if(list.isEmpty()) 
{
    Log.e("Connection Setup","Empty list returned");
}

for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
    if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
    Log.e("Connection Setup",i.SSID+" connrction attempted");
    wifiManager.disconnect();
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
    wifiManager.reconnect();               
    break;
 }           
}
```

I have been trying more things - if I make this thread sleep for about 10 seconds or so - everything works fine - but is there a better alternative?

Comment: Have you tried w/o SSID, status and priority? Does it see it then?

Comment: @bluewhite I guess i at least need the SSID, i tried without the other two but it still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 1):

You can not continue the

```
CMD wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()
```

until the status of WiFi is enabled completely. For enabling the WiFi it need some time. So you need to delay some time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment these lines in your code.. do you see any change in result set?

```
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);   
wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
```

You might want to check the return for `wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);`, is it returning -1.

For me this lines return 31 objects only.. no idea why..still hunting for it.

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
List<WifiConfiguration> arraylist = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
Log.wtf("WifiPreference","No of Networks"+arraylist.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

I also met this question unfortunely.

After searching for some time, I think it is a bug.

This is the android implement of getConfiguredNetworks

```
public List<WifiConfiguration> getConfiguredNetworks() {
    try {
        return mService.getConfiguredNetworks();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It is clearly shown that the function will return null if RemoteException happened when running. Up to now, I am also distressed with this and could not get some points to address this issue.

For more information:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19078

Answer (score 0):

Since new Android versions (I think since Android 12) you also need to add COARSE_LOCATION permission to your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Then you can use (Android <= 28):

```
List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
```

For Android >= 29:

```
wifiManager.getScanResults()
```