# Android: unable to connect to WiFi network prammatically

Tags: java, android, wifi

I'm trying to connect a specific Wifi using the following:

```
if (wifiChecking.isWifiEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Wifi is working ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            String networkSSID = "adhocNet";
            Toast.makeText(this, "Wifi is off ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            wifiChecking.setWifiEnabled(true);

            WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
            conf.SSID = "\"\"" + networkSSID + "\"\"";
            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
            wifiChecking.addNetwork(conf);

            List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiChecking.getConfiguredNetworks();
            for (WifiConfiguration i : list) {
                if (i.SSID != null
                        && i.SSID.equals("\"\"" + networkSSID + "\"\"")) {
                    wifiChecking.disconnect();
                    wifiChecking.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                    System.out.print("i.networkId " + i.networkId + "\n");
                    wifiChecking.reconnect();
                    break;

                }
            }
        }
```

However, it always crashes at this line:

```
for (WifiConfiguration i : list ){
```

Here is LogCat output:

```
04-15 13:29:14.010: W/dalvikvm(3476): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415837c0)
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3640)
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4247)
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17728)
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3635)
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476):     ... 11 more
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476):     at com.example.testApp.MainActivity.enableAdohcNetworking(MainActivity.java:52)
04-15 13:29:14.020: E/AndroidRuntime(3476):     ... 14 more
```

**Any idea what might be the problem ?!**

*note that I am trying to connect to an ad-hoc network and the device is rooted and*

Comment: can you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: @Blackbelt: only as an image, I don't know how to print it as text !

Comment: you have a NullPointerException on the line 52 in MainActivity

Comment: @Blackbelt: Line 52 is the same "for-loop" line mentioned above .. what might be the cause for this ?!!

Comment: I see, then list is null. The documentation for `getConfiguredNetworks` says *Upon failure to fetch or when when Wi-Fi is turned off, it can be null.*

Comment: have you added the wifi related required permissions in manifest ?

Comment: @Blackbelt: first of all, thank you for pointing out the main issue. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22592353/2135363) question with relate to same issue. So, I added 10s delay using `Thread.Sleep(10000)` to give more time to actually obtain the available SSIDs. The result is: it partially works as it doesn't crash, however it does not connect to my specified network.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(10000)` sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: @Blackbelt: Regards the Manifest permissions, yes, I've added the follwoing: `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`,`ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` and `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`.

Comment: @Blackbelt: well, that is what I thought of: to give more time to obtain the complete SSIDs list (avoiding NULL return) .. nonetheless, I am welcome to any suggestion of better implementation .. I am here to learn :-)

Comment: use a Handler. Post a runnable, with `postDelayed`

Comment: @Blackbelt: Thank you very much .. However, I am a newbe to android (and java alike). I will look into this `postDelayed` in more details. Meanwhile, I am still unable to connect to my specified network !!