# Missing networkId in WifiConfiguration and WiFiInfo on Nexus 5 (6.0)

Tags: android, wifimanager, nexus-5, wifi

I need a networkId of currently connected WiFi in order to disconnect device from that WiFi:

```
wifiManager.disconnect()
wifiManager.removeNetwork(i.networkId);
wifiManager.saveConfiguration()
```

I tried

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
```

In both case, networkId is 0

On Galaxy S5 it works OK.

Any ideas, workarounds....?

Comment: I suppose the Galaxy S5 doesn't have android 6.0

Comment: @abbath Yes, it is 5.0

Comment: Yeah, then it can be because of the 6.0 permission behaviour, as I mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From Android 6.0, permission behaviour has changed to runtime. To use a feature that requires a permission, one should check first if the permission is granted previously. Using `checkSelfPermission(permissionString)` method a result is returned, wither ther permission is `PERMISSION_GRANTED` or `PERMISSION_DENIED`.

If permission isn't granted or it is first time, a request for permission should be made. Giving a user an option to grant or deny.

For more information check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151603/scan-results-available-action-return-empty-list-in-android-6-0).

Comment: Hm.. I am not targeting API 23. I understood that it will work in that case. If I am not right, that means all "older" apps will not work on 6.0 without new permission handling?

Comment: [Check this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592353/wifimanager-getconfigurednetworks-always-returns-empty-list), it can be a bug.